# Query a `perf.data` file for the total raw execution time of a symbol

Tags: performance, optimization, performance-testing, perf

I used [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) to generate a perf file with `perf record ./application`. `perf report` shows me various things about it. How can I show the total time it took to run the application, and the total time to run a specific "symbol"/function? perf seems to often show percentages, but I want raw time, and it want "inclusive" time, i.e. including children.

perf v4.15.18 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04

Answer (score 5):

perf is [statistical (sampling) profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers) (in its default `perf record` mode), and it means it have no exact timestamps on function entry and exit (tracing is required for exact data). Perf asks OS kernel to generate interrupts thousands times per second (4 kHz for hardware PMU if `-e cycles` supported, less for software event `-e cpu-clock`). Every interrupt of program execution is recorded as sample which contains EIP (current instruction pointer), pid (process/thread id), timestamp of current time. When program runs for several seconds, there will be thousands of samples, and `perf report` can generate histograms from them: which parts of program code (which functions) were executed more often than other. You will get generic overview that some functions did take around 30% of program execution time while other - 5%.

perf report does not compute total program execution time (it may estimate it by comparing timestamps of first and last sample, but it is not exact if there were off-CPU periods). But it does estimate total event count (it is printed in first line in interactive TUI and is listed in text output):

```
$ perf report |grep approx
# Samples: 1K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 844373507
```

There is `perf report -n` option which adds column "number of samples" next to percent column.

```
Samples: 1K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 861416907
Overhead       Samples  Command  Shared Object     Symbol
  42.36%           576  bc       bc                [.] _bc_rec_mul
  37.49%           510  bc       bc                [.] _bc_shift_addsub.isra.3
  14.90%           202  bc       bc                [.] _bc_do_sub
   0.89%            12  bc       bc                [.] bc_free_num
```

But samples are taken not at same intervals and they are less exact than computed overhead (every sample may have different weight). I will recommend you to run `perf stat ./application` to have real total running time and total hardware counts for your application. It is better when your application has stable running time (do `perf stat -r 5 ./application` to have variation estimated by tool as "+-  0.28%" in last column)

To include children functions stack traces must be sampled at every interrupt. They are not sampled in default `perf record` mode. This sampling is turned on with `-g`  or  `--call-graph dwarf` options: `perf record -g ./application` or `perf record --call-graph dwarf ./application`. It is not simple to use it correctly for preinstalled libraries or applications in Linux (as most distributions strip debug information from packages), but can be used for your own applications compiled with debug information. The default `-g` which is same as `--call-graph fp` requires that all code is compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` gcc option, and non-default `--call-graph dwarf` is more reliable. With correctly prepared program and libraries, single-threaded application, and long enough stack size samples (8KB is default, change with `--call-graph dwarf,65536`), `perf report` should show around 99% for `_start` and `main` functions (including children).

bc calculator compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`:

```
bc-no-omit-frame$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf record -g  bc/bc
bc-no-omit-frame$ perf report
Samples: 1K of event 'cycles:uppp', Event count (approx.): 811063902
  Children      Self  Command  Shared Object       Symbol
+   98.33%     0.00%  bc       [unknown]           [.] 0x771e258d4c544155
+   98.33%     0.00%  bc       libc-2.27.so        [.] __libc_start_main
+   98.33%     0.00%  bc       bc                  [.] main
```

bc calculator with dwarf call graph:

```
$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf record --call-graph dwarf  bc/bc
$ perf report
Samples: 1K of event 'cycles:uppp', Event count (approx.): 898828479
  Children      Self  Command  Shared Object     Symbol
+   98.42%     0.00%  bc       bc                [.] _start
+   98.42%     0.00%  bc       libc-2.27.so      [.] __libc_start_main
+   98.42%     0.00%  bc       bc                [.] main
```

bc without debug info has incorrect call graph handling by perf in `-g` (fp) mode (no 99% for main):

```
$ cp bc/bc bc.strip
$ strip -d bc.strip
$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf record --call-graph fp ./bc.strip 
Samples: 1K of event 'cycles:uppp', Event count (approx.): 841993392
  Children      Self  Command   Shared Object     Symbol
+   43.94%    43.94%  bc.strip  bc.strip          [.] _bc_rec_mul
+   39.73%    39.73%  bc.strip  bc.strip          [.] _bc_shift_addsub.isra.3
+   11.27%    11.27%  bc.strip  bc.strip          [.] _bc_do_sub
+    0.92%     0.92%  bc.strip  libc-2.27.so      [.] malloc
```

Sometimes `perf report --no-children` can be useful to disable sorting on self+children overhead (will sort by "self" overhead), for example when call graph was not fully captured.